# Using Substring function on date field in group by clause in SQL

Tags: mysql, date, group-by

I have a table  named goods which has 2 fields

```
purchase_id,date_of_purchase.
```

The data types of the fields are

```
purchase_id ----INT,
date_of_purchase -----DATE field. format: yyyy-mm--dd
```

the tuples might look like

```
1,2013-01-19
2,2013-01-20
3,2013-02-15
```

I want to aggregate purchase_id by year-months only.
I want to count number of purchases by months.

The date is of the format yyyy-mm-dd.

I am trying to write a query like

```
select count(purchase_id)
from goods
group by 'substring(date_of_purchase,1,7)';
```

But the query doesn't work.

Result:
I get the count of purchase_id in the table. NOT by each month.

Can anybody point what mistake I am making?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a useful problem description. What happens? No results? An error?

Comment: Separately: Is `date_of_purchase` a `char`/`varchar` field? Not a `date`?